# Angular.js & HTML / how to combine 2 elements side by side

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code in HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
   <span class="col-sm-9" ng-repeat="app1 in allDesc[$index]"> {{app1}}</span>
   <label ng-repeat="app2 in allValues[$index]"><input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" style="width: 30%" ng-model="app2" ng-disabled="app2" id="inputPassword1" required="" disabled="disabled"></input>
   </label>
</div>
<div>
```

The problem is that all the span elements are written one after the other, and so the inputs elements. I want that every span will be printed near the input.

I try also the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
   <span class="col-sm-9" ng-repeat="app1 in allDesc[$index]"> {{app1}}
   <label ng-repeat="app2 in allValues[$index]"><input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" style="width: 30%" ng-model="app2" ng-disabled="app2" id="inputPassword1" required="" disabled="disabled"></input>
      </span>
   </label>
</div>
<div>
```

But then it prints only the first value of allDesc.

How can I do it with `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Are `allValues` and `allDesc` the same length?

Comment: why do you need an empty label wrapping a a text input. that's not very accessible

Comment: @charlietfl: Because allValues and allDesc are arrays also.

Comment: @OrSmith  - I'm not sure what the question is, but this fiddle shows all the spans printed next to all of the inputs that are created. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kshreve/j9turL0d/)

Comment: that doesn't explain the incorrect use of `<label>`

Comment: @kshreve: But I wish that span1 will be printed, and then input1, span2, input2, and so on..

Comment: @charlietfl Wrapping your input within a label is valid HTML, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL

Answer (score 1):

If `allDesc` and `allValues` arrays have the same length, you should create only one container with `ng-repeat` directive either for `allDesc` or `allValues` items and then use `$index` to bind to items in the array not used for `ng-repeat`. Here is example code using `allDesc` in `ng-repeat`:

```
   <div class="col-sm-9">
     <div ng-repeat="desc in allDesc">
       <span class="col-sm-9">{{desc}}</span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="allValues[$index]"/>
    </div>
   </div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stubb0rn/j9turL0d/9/) with this code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kshreve/j9turL0d/5/) is what you are after?

Crux of the issue being how the data was formatted. Creating a new model, and ng-repeating above where you are currently will help.

```
var test = {};
test.span = 'a';
test.input = '1';

var models.push(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

`</input>` This is not valid HTML. `<input>` has no closing tag.  And as far as your question goes here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9turL0d/6/). This should get you on the right path.

```
<div ng-app="orSmith" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label ng-repeat="item in allValues">{{item}}
        <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" style="width: 30%" ng-model="app2" ng-disabled="app2" id="inputPassword1" required="" disabled="disabled" />
    </label>
</div>

  angular.module('orSmith', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.allValues = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
      $scope.allDesc = ['test', 'test2'];
  });
```